# Getting error while creating a contract using token

Tags: solidity, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am very new into this, while following this guide. 
[Ethereum Token](https://www.ethereum.org/token)

I am getting error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract MyToken {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* This notifies clients about the amount burnt */
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /* Approve and then communicate the approved contract in a single tx */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }        

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                                // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;     // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                           // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                             // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                      // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                                // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                               // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> "throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()".
>           if (_to == 0x0) throw;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead

Tried many code but getting same error, please help me to fix this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to get it to compile is to change every instance of the `throw` keyword in the code to `revert()`.  Revert is the improved way to do abnormal terminations of a contract.

Nicer would be to rewrite each expression that currently uses `throw` to use the `require()` function to check input parameters and terminate if they are not met. It is [documented here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions). Under the hood it's doing much the same thing as the `if (...) revert()` statements, so it's just a stylistic thing.